# PHP 7.4.21 - A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php, warnings

I have an array with float/int values I'm trying to build into a string to encode to json but keep getting a "Warning : A non-numeric value encountered" error. Below is a stripped down version of the issue and a few things I've tried with no luck. Anyone spot any stupid mistakes or know the cause of this issue? Thanks greatly.

```
//I've tried casting as a string, putting the numeric value in quotes, using the strVal()    
//function to no luck.
$angle = "";
$angles2 = array(100, 90, 80);

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
    //no luck with any of these
    $angle = strVal($angles2[$i]);
    //$angle = (string)$angles2[$i];
    //$angle = "$angles2[$i]";
    //$angle = $angles2[$i] . "";
    
    $anglesStr += $angle;
}
```

Comment: why is there an open bracket before 90 in $angles2 = array(100, (90, 80); ?

Comment: What is `$angles2 = array(100, (90, 80);`? Why not do `foreach($angles2 as $angle2){ ...`

Comment: @KenLee : Just an accidental artifact left from trying to cast, corrected, thanks.

Comment: @user3783243 : It threw the same warning with a foreach loop.

Comment: `$anglesStr` in addition to answer `$anglesStr` should be initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$anglesStr += $angle;
```

This is a numeric addition, while you want string concatenation

```
$anglesStr .= $angle;
```

eg. 2+4

The first line would return 6 while second returns 24 (if valid data types).